# Directory vanished when I pressed Ctrl+H or some other shortcut - how can I get it back?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, directory

I've been working on this project for a whole weekend on Ubuntu 16.04

I went to the project directory, thought I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> (to see `.git` folder) and boof, the directory is gone and can't be found anymore.

What could have happened? Is there any way to go back?

There is like 12h of uncommitted work just gone...

Comment: Sure you didn't just hide it? Use terminal, `ls` to list files/folders from within the folder.

Comment: just an single .idea directory there now :(

Comment: No hope for the recycle bin?

Comment: Nothing there either, i have no idea what happend.

Comment: Found it with grep... jesus.... scared me real good.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what happend. But if you find yourself in same situation, maybe try grep -R if you have any idea of contents.

Found mine in different folder with name Untitled Folder.

Atleast its not gone..

That was scary